# How do I use environment variables in .env file in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker

I am trying to use an environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I have a file `my-great-env.env`.

Here is how they look:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    blahblah:
        images: greatimage
        volumes:
          - "${MY_PATH}:c:\\FinalFolder"
```

**my-great-env.env**

```
MY_PATH=C:\the\path\to\folder
```

When I try to docker run this, I get

> The MY_PATH variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

How do I use the environment variables defined in the `.env` file in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: I doubt that docker can swallow `C:\the\path\to\folder` windows style. and for yaml vars you just do:`- MY_PATH:/c/FinalFolder`

Comment: It has worked if I hard code the path in there. Now I'm trying to extract it out to a file of environment variables and can't get the syntax right.

Comment: my-great-env.env != .env

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two aspects of your problem:

1. if you want to use the environment vars in `docker-compose.yml` file, you have to put them in file named `.env` as stated here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file
2. you can use the `env_file` configuration option to use any file with variables definitions as described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option BUT! they will be visible only in containers, not in the `docker-compose.yml` file.